# Refused to connect to URL because it violates CSP

Tags: javascript, socket.io, content-security-policy, ngrok, helmet.js

I'm building a program that uses helmet as a security layer on the server side. I fetch from the GitLab API. And I use socket.io to communicate with gitlab. I also use ngrok to get a temporary url for gitlab to send requests to while I work on localhost.

When opening the application, every few seconds I get this error:

Refused to connect to 'https://.ngrok.iosocket.io/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Why does this happen? I tried to add the ngrok url as connect-src but that didn't help.

This is what my helmet CSP looks like:

```
app.use(helmet())

  app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
      directives: {
        ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
        'script-src': ["'self'", 'code.jquery.com', 'cdn.jsdelivr.net', "'unsafe-eval'"]

      }
    })
  )
```

Comment: _Did_ you try to add ngrok as a connect-src? That's not in what you've shown.

Comment: `getDefaultDirectives()` does not contain `connect-src`, but `default-src 'self'`. Therefore connections are allowed to self-domain only. Pls note that `.ngrok.iosocket.io` is started with a dot - this is wrong.